# Load specific data from array

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

So i have this class for loading data from my MySQL database :

```
class Db {

    protected static $connection;

    public function connect() {    
        if(!isset(static::$connection)) {
            $config = parse_ini_file('config.ini'); 
            static::$connection = new mysqli('localhost',$config['username'],$config['password'],$config['dbname']);
        }
        if(static::$connection === false) {
            return false;
        }
        return static::$connection;
    }


    public function query($query) {
        return $this->connect()->query($query);
    }

    public function select($query) {
        $rows = array();
        $result = $this->query($query);
        if($result === false) {
            return false;
        }
        while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
            $rows[] = $row;
        }
        return $rows;
    }

    public function error() {
        return $this->connect()->error;
    }

    public function quote($value) {
        return "'" . $this->connect()->real_escape_string($value) . "'";
    }
}
```

I use that class like this :

```
$db = new Db();
$rows = $db -> select("SELECT name, shortlink FROM `test` WHERE id=3");
```

It gives me an array with the data.

The problem is that i want to pull out specific data, for example the shortlink field.

How do i do that? I have tried `echo $rows['shortlink']`, but that gives me the following error :

> Undefined index: shortlink

So how do I print specific data?

Comment: I would suggest using more convenient approach to fetch values of a certain field with PDO (PDO::FETCH_COLUMN)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your returned `$rows` columns is an array of associative arrays, to pull out `shortlink` data returned from the query you have to do something like this:

```
foreach($rows as $row) {
   echo $row['shortlink'];
}
```